# Images Not Uploading in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller

I'm working on a blog site and I want a feature where authors could upload images to be included with the post. I had it working just fine, but it was keeping the original file names. I figured this could be a problem in the future, so I tried making a GUID to avoid conflicts. This is what I'm looking at in my controller right now:

```
if (ImageUploadHelper.IsWebFriendlyImage(image))
{
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);
    image.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), ext));
    blogPost.MediaUrl = "/Uploads/" + Guid.NewGuid() + ext;
}
```

...the "ImageUploadHelper" being a helper method to handle files that are too big and/or not the correct format. Anyway, as it is right now, posts can be created and I can see in SSMS that the MediaUrl is being saved in what looks like the correct format, but the files are not actually uploading and thus not displaying. Previously, I had this:

```
if (ImageUploadHelper.IsWebFriendlyImage(image))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
    image.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fileName));
    blogPost.MediaUrl = "/Uploads/" + fileName;
}
```

...and everything was working well, with the exception that there was a potential for filename conflicts. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are saving just extensions?

```
image.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), ext));
```

So, please use this instead:

```
var newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ext;
image.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), newFileName));
blogPost.MediaUrl = "/Uploads/" + newFileName;
```